# How can I get my shared preferences?

Tags: android, facebook, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to do a simple Facebook Login in my app, but I got some questions about SharedPreferences.

The idea is the App starts and goes to Activity A, it sees if you're logged in, if you aren't then it sends you to Activity B, you login and go back to A.

What's happening is that when I log in at B, it sends me back to A, but A doesn't appear to load my SharedPreferences and send me back to B, and I got into a loop.

That's my code in A.

```
public static String access_token = null;
long expires;
```

...

```
private void SharedP() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(access_token, MODE_PRIVATE);
    access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
    expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if (access_token == null && expires == 0) { //If it's not logged...
        Intent login = new Intent("android.intent.action.FACEBOOKLOGIN");
        startActivity(login);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I do it?

My code in B:

```
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Editor edit = fbSP.edit();
                edit.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                edit.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                edit.commit();
                UpdateLoginImage();
                BackToA();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not reading the same shared preferences on A and B.

`getSharedPreferences(access_token, MODE_PRIVATE)`opens an "access_token" shared preferences file, you should use a file name like `getSharedPreferences("facebook_data", MODE_PRIVATE)`.

Then in activity B, if you follow the Facebook guide on login for android, it uses the activity sharedPreferences `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)`. This second one returns a preferences file only accesible for the activity B. I'm just guessing this because i don't have your code, maybe you got that ok.

Check if you are opening the same sharedPreferences file on both activities.

Comment: I edited my post with my more code. I don't think I'm calling for another Shared Preference.

Comment: In B you make `fbSP.edit()`, but how did you initialize fbSP?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention! Thank you, I forgot that I was using "getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)" instead of "getSharedPreferences("facebook_data", MODE_PRIVATE)". Everything is working now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When you store your SharedPreferences in ActivityB, make sure to call `commit()` to save the preferences.

Like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("loggedIn", isLoggedIn);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I called it. I don't think the problem is in B, because when in B, it automatically goes to A and show the logout button instead of the login, so looks like that everything there is fine.

Comment: @VictorDomingosSantiago Can you post how you store it anyways?  The only way to mess up your SharedPreferences really would be using the wrong key.  You are calling SharedP() in onResume() right?  Going back to ActivityA from ActivityB will only call onResume().

Comment: I'm calling SharedP() in onCreate in A.

Answer (score 0):

This should be hepful. You have to convert this better into your situation:

In A:

```
private boolean isLogged;

// Check if the user is logged
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
isLogged= settings.getBoolean("isLogged", false);
```

... then compare:

```
if (!isLogged) {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setClass(A.this, B.class);
     startActivity(intent);
} else {
     // Do anything
}
```

In B:

```
// ... after login
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLogged", true);
editor.commit();
```

Best Regards